# JQuery Chosen plugin not showing results

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I'm using an api to get data which has to populate my select. When I inspect the element in Chrome I can see the select filled with the options but in the `<ul class="chosen-results">` there is nothing.

I'm also using Bootstrap but I deleted it from my code to check for conflicts so I'm thinking this isn't the problem.

```
<select name="tags" id="tags" class="chosen-select" multiple data-placeholder="Add tags"></select>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("http://path/to/api", function(data) {
        var option = '';

        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            option += '<option value="'+ data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>';
        }

        $('#tags').append(option);

    });

    $('#tags').chosen({width: "100%"});
});
```

My JSON looks like this

```
[
 "lorem",
 "ipsum",
 "dolor"
]
```

Comment: *"but in the <ul class="chosen-results"> there is nothing"* - as you've not shown us any code to do with that element, how do you expect anyone to answer your question? Also, Youve mentioned a "chosen" plugin, but you've not linked to it

Comment: this element is created by the chosen plugin, these values are filled with the ones you declare in your options

Comment: Works fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/572vkt6a/)**.. Check for any console errors

Comment: Yes when I add the option hardcoded it works as well for me, but when adding it from my api it doesn't. I have no errors in console

Comment: Try `parsing` the `json` returned I mean something like `var returnedData=$.parseJSON(data)` and then loop with `returnedData`

Comment: I added an answer, don't really know why it's working now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

> If you need to update the options in your select field and want Chosen to pick up the changes, you'll need to trigger the "chosen:updated" event on the field. Chosen will re-build itself based on the updated content.

Therefore, you probably want to tell the plugin you've updated the option having filled them all in from your ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("http://path/to/api", function(data) {
        var option = '';

        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            option += '<option value="'+ data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>';
        }

        $('#tags').append(option);
        // notify the plugin we've updated the options.
        $("#tags").trigger("chosen:updated");

    });

    $('#tags').chosen({width: "100%"});
});
```